# Internal server error in opencart checkout

Tags: opencart, checkout, internal-server-error

I have a project running using **opencart**, and it was working fine. But suddenly when the user moves to entering the credit card information it gives him an internal server error.

When I checked the error log I found the following

> 2017-04-23 2:49:25 - PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: class in D:\home\site\wwwroot\opencartar\catalog\view\theme\customTheme\template\common\success.tpl

on line 32